# How to insert values into SQL Server 2008 using PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert the value into the SQL Server 2008 using PHP code.
This is my code:

```
<?php
// connect to sql.
include 'db_config.php';
// input into sql database

$query ="INSERT INTO State ('StateID', 'State', 'StateCode', 'CountryId')     VALUES (203, 'Dehli', 'DH', 100)";

/* Prepare and execute the query. */
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query);

if( $stmt )
{
echo "Row successfully inserted.\n";
}
else
{
echo "Row insertion failed.\n";
die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// close the connection
sqlsrv_close( $conn);

?>
```

I am getting following error:

> Connection established Row insertion failed. Array ( [0] => Array (
>   [0] => 42S22 [SQLSTATE] => 42S22 [1] => 207 [code] => 207 [2] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column
>   name 'StateID'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL
>   Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'StateID'. ) [1] => Array ( [0]
>   => 42S22 [SQLSTATE] => 42S22 [1] => 207 [code] => 207 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column
>   name 'State'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL
>   Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'State'. ) [2] => Array ( [0]
>   => 42S22 [SQLSTATE] => 42S22 [1] => 207 [code] => 207 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column
>   name 'StateCode'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL
>   Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'StateCode'. ) [3] => Array (
>   [0] => 42S22 [SQLSTATE] => 42S22 [1] => 207 [code] => 207 [2] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column
>   name 'CountryId'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL
>   Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'CountryId'. ) )

Comment: open your eyes `Invalid column name 'CountryId'`

Comment: And you don't need to use **'** inverted commas around your table name and if you insist then use **`** backtics instead and yeah its not compulsory to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says it all

> Invalid column name 'StateID'. Invalid column name 'State' Invalid
>   column name 'StateCode' Invalid column name 'CountryId'

Column names in your `INSERT` statement should not be enclosed in single quotes `(')` . You should write the column names as is or enclosed in `[]` like below

```
$query ="INSERT INTO State (StateID, State, StateCode, CountryId)     VALUES (203, 'Dehli', 'DH', 100)";
```

OR

```
$query ="INSERT INTO [State] ([StateID], [State], [StateCode], [CountryId])     VALUES (203, 'Dehli', 'DH', 100)";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's clear in the error message:

```
Invalid column name 'CountryId'
Invalid column name 'State'
```